# How to get location from the different places in NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I dynamically want to check text field for correctness. I have the vocabulary with permitted letter. For example, you may not type 'Q' letter. If you type it at the end of text, then I check only last letter if vocabulary contains it. If not, then subString to the previous letter.

But what if I insert letter in the middle or somewhere else? How can I catch where this letter added and check it?

Comment: Look at the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods, and `NSString` methods, like : `rangeOfString:`, `hasSuffix:`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that as bellow

```
[textField addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField
{
    NSRange aRange = [theTextField.text rangeOfString:@"q"];
    if(aRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found Q");
    }
}
```

Comment: But how now I should delete this symbol if I do not know it's location? `range.location` sets not to location in `NSString`.

Comment: You can do that with NSString *aStr = theTextField.text;
    [aStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"q" withString:@""];
    theTextField.text = aStr;

Comment: Hmm, I've got another question about this. `NSString *aStr = theTextField.text; [aStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"q" withString:@""]; theTextField.text = aStr;` What if there are more letters to delete then just `@"q"`? Maybe I can get the current position of inserted symbol?

Comment: May be are you looking for this delegate method - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

Comment: No, in dynamic insertion argument `replacment string` is unknown if I insert letter in the middle or somewhere else. I'm just curious if it is possible to callback position of the current inserted symbol.

Comment: You can do that as bellow - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
        UITextRange *selRange = textField.selectedTextRange;
        UITextPosition *selStartPos = selRange.start;
    
    return YES;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60080/discussion-between-user3360601-and-rajesh).